# How to send data from my node script to a function in the client script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn Node.JS by building my own inventory management system. I am trying to learn how to pass data from the HTML page and Client JS script to the server and then return the data to the client JS script.

So far I have created a basic HTML page with the form, I created a client JS script, and Index/Server JS script. The server is the node and uses nedb as the database, and webpack.

My current issue is I can't get the data sent to the server from the HTML form to go to the Client.js function. I have tried using response.sendFile and a few other response. commands but the server keeps saying response.x is not a function (x being sendfile/render/etc...). I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have included the HTML form, server script and client-side function.

HTML

```
<div>
    <form action='/inventory' method='POST'>
           <input type="text" name='Name' value="Name"/>
           <input type="text" name='Model-Num' value="Model Number"/>
           <input type="text" name='Current-Stock' value="Current Stock Amount"/>
           <input type="text" name='Target-Stock' value="Target Stock"/>
           <input type="text" name='Reorder-Amount' value="Reorder Amount"/>


            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
    </form>

</div>
```

==============================

SERVER

```
app.post('/inventory', urlencodedParser ,(req, response, next) => {

  console.log('Im not broken');

  console.log("I got a req");
  console.log(req.body)

  response = {
      status: "success",
      code : 200,
      hype : "SO hyped",
  }

  console.log("res" , response);

  next();


});
```

=======================

CLIENT

```
function printHTML(e)
{
    console.log("e " , e);
}
```

I just want the data object from the node function to go to the client-side function.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I fixed the response problem but am still lost on how to pass the JSON object to my client side function

Answer (score 0):

You need response.status(200).json(yourobject). No need for next() in the route handler.

Answer (score 0):

A major problem is, that you don't have a way to receive the response from the server in the client-side Javascript.

Have you heard about [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) before? If not, then take a look at it. With AJAX, you can make server calls and get responses back from the server. In your current code, you have no way to receive the server response.

Also, you have the parameter `response` and then later

```
response = {
    status: "success",
    code : 200,
    hype : "SO hyped",
}
```

which overwrites the parameter. This way, `response` doesn't have the functionalities of the parameter (render, sendFile, etc.) anymore, but of the object, which you defined. So, it is definitely necessary to rename either the parameter or the object.

Comment: question: is it bad design to have the information from the form go to a function in the client script get bundled into a fetch and then go to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your response object, which was passed as a parameter from the route handler. Try use a different variable name so you don't overwrite it.

```
app.post('/inventory', urlencodedParser, (req, response, next) => {
  console.log('Im not broken');
  console.log("I got a req");
  console.log(req.body);

  const returnToClient = {
    status: "success",
    code: 200,
    hype: "SO hyped"
  };

  // You could also use response.send() here, but your response is an 
  // object so it's better to use response.json()
  response.json(returnToClient);
});
```

Also if you're sending a response back to the client, then you wouldn't really need to use the next() function.